# iabbrev with autocompletition

Tags: autocompletion

I had setup the following `iabbrev` for my Verilog settings:

```
iabbrev module module<Enter>(<Enter><Enter>);<Up><Up><Up><End>
iabbrev begin begin<Enter><Enter>end<Up><Tab>
iabbrev else else begin<Enter><Enter>end<Up><Tab>
iabbrev if if<Space>(<Space>)<Space>begin<Enter><Enter>end<Up><Tab>
```

It works quiet well (I could improve it), but I have a small problem: it only works if I don't use the autocompletion suggestions: for example, in the following screenshot, if I *choose* the `module` suggestion, the `iabbrev` directive doesn't work.

[image]

How can I make it work with autocompletition in an elegant way ?
Perhaps using a function would do the job...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work", exactly?

Comment: Well, I realize I had been wrong saying that it doesn't work"... More correctly, I would like to avoid the use of the <Space>...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: since I want to avoid the space needed for the `iabbrev`, without using `C-]`, following the `:h abbreviations` suggestion this is my own solution:

```
iabbrev <buffer> always always<Space>@()<Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
iabbrev <buffer> module module<Enter>(<Enter><Enter>);<Up><Up><Up><End><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
iabbrev <buffer> begin begin<Enter><Enter>end<Up><Tab><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
iabbrev <buffer> else else begin<Enter><Enter>end<Up><Tab><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
iabbrev <buffer> if if<Space>(<Space>)<Space>begin<Enter><Enter>end<Up><Tab><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
```